# How to get the Dataflow template of a Dataprep job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

The client I work for is going to deprecate Dataprep in October, we currently work everything with Google Cloud Platform.

Dataprep is a "pretty" layer that runs under dataflow,

currently, one of the implemented solutions consists of: a file is received in a bucket, and with python I execute the dataprep.

https://www.trifacta.com/blog/automate-cloud-dataprep-pipeline-data-warehouse/

**I need to know how I can obtain the template of those dataprep jobs so that when the file is received in the bucket I can trigger the dataflow corresponding to that dataprep and if I can eliminate dataprep from the solution.**

https://mbha-phoenix.medium.com/running-cloud-dataprep-jobs-on-cloud-dataflow-for-more-control-37ed84e73cf3

Dataprep previously allowed you to do this, but this option is no longer available.

[Screenshot: "Export Result Window"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mJyZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The export option is no longer available in DataPrep.  From the DataPrep -> Job History, you can view the previously executed Dataflow job, but can not export
[image: View Dataflow Job]